# Posting dynamically added html table rows to controller as parameter - ASP.NET Core/MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

In the table shown below, a row is created dynamically and I'm using `@Html.BeginForm` to submit the data not jQuery ajax. Is there any better way to do that?

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sortable" id="tab_logic">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">
                Degree / Diploma / Certificate
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Name Of Board / University
            </th>
            <th class="text-center table-cell-label">
                Passing Year
            </th>
            <th class="text-center" style="border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;">
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{
            int i = 0;

            foreach (var item in Model.qualifications.ToList())
            {
                <tr class="hidden">
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(o => o.qualifications[i].AcedamicQualification, new { @id="AcedamicQualification" + i, @name = "AcedamicQualification", @class ="form-control" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(o => o.qualifications[i].Board, new { @id="Board" + i, @name = "Board", @class ="form-control" })
                    </td>
                    
                    <td>
                        <button name="del0" class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove'></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                i++;
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Model by which I'm trying to bind the dynamically added row

```
public class AdmissionFormViewModel
{
    public List<Qualification> qualifications { get; set; }
}

public class Qualification
{
    public string AcedamicQualification { get; set; }
    public string Board { get; set; }
    public string PassingYear { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller

```
public IActionResult PostAdmission(AdmissionFormViewModel admissionFormViewModel)
{
    return View("/School/Form");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Form post don't need to write js.ajax don't need to refresh page.Your Action `PostAdmission` means you want to redirect after post,and your view code has bound the model,so I think form post is better.

If you want to pass the whole model,you only need to put the table in a form,If you also want to pass `PassingYear` to model,you can use the following code in `foreach`

```
   <input asp-for="@item.PassingYear" name="qualifications[i].PassingYear" hidden/>
```

And I find the code

```
@id = "AcedamicQualification" + i, @name = "AcedamicQualification"
@id="Board" + i, @name = "Board"
```

didn't change id or name.You can remove them.When bind the model, name needs to be `qualifications[i].xxx`.

If you only want to submit one row, you can put form inside foreach.